# can you add subdivision surface modifiers to specific vertex groups

Tags: modeling, vertices, vertex-groups, subdivision-surface

i want to make parts of my model seem more smooth but others i want to stay flat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you can't use **Vertex Groups** for **Subdivision Surface** modifier.

What you can do is select region you want to have smoother and use <kbd>W</kbd> > **Subdivide Smooth**.

Be aware that this method will create ngons and/or tris (when **Quad/Tri Mode** is checked).

[image: subd]

Comment: In 2.83 and later (and possibly earlier), The process is to right-click and then click subdivide and change the "Smoothness" setting to 1

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you can not do that, but you can use the knife tool to make cuts on the surface, 
to access the tool touch the <kbd>k</kbd> or in the t menu on the left side of your screen in edit mode. 
also remember that if two sides are very close to each other it will give the illusion that  the area is flatter

here I leave you an image as an example

[image]